In Nx workspace , Is it possible to combine Nestjs api server with Angular v17 ssr server?
Im using Nx workspace, is it possible to deploy both the Nest js api and Angular v17 ssr server as a single project in Vercel or any other hosting platforms ?
This is my dist folder, I have my nestjs api in api folder and angular v17 project in realestate-x2 folder, since it uses ssr, I have server.mjs inside the server folder for angular project.

